# How to get byte type (eg. Byte or Int16) from GeoTIFF imported into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, geotiff-tiff

I have imported a `raster` into PostGIS, and would like to know the "byte type," ie. if the orignal GeoTIFF was a `Byte` type or `Int16`.

Is this possible to do after importing to PostGIS? If so, how? Or must it be done on the GeoTIFF file itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under your public schema you should have a [raster_columns](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Raster_Columns) view which serves as a catalogue for all raster columns in your database. One of the columns in the view is pixel_types which lists the pixel type for each band.

If you used the raster2pgsql utility these details should be updated automatically. Otherwise you may have to run the [AddRasterConstraints](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/RT_AddRasterConstraints.html) function.

To access via SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM raster_columns;
```

or, for a specific table:

```
SELECT * FROM raster_columns
WHERE r_table_schema = 'name_of_the_schema_your_table_is_in'
    and r_table_name = 'name_of_your_raster_table';
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to access this with a `SELECT` command?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an SQL query example.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
SELECT ST_BandPixelType(rast)
FROM yourrastertable
```

http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_BandPixelType.html